# Unity testing Singleton with NUnit

Tags: unity-game-engine, testing, nunit

I have a Unity Project which should create a HoloLens Application. Now i want to test some of my Code in Unity with NUnit. I created some PlayMode tests

```
public class Test
{
    private GameObject empty;

    [SetUp]
    public void BeforEveryTest()
    {
        empty = new GameObject();
        empty.AddComponent<MainController>();
    }
    // A Test behaves as an ordinary method
    [Test]
    public void MainControllerGetInstance()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(MainController.Instance);
    }
}
```

This is the Singleton I want to test

```
public class MainController : Singleton<MainController>
{

[SerializeField]
private GameObject SomePref;

private void Start()
{
    SomePrefab.SetActive(true);
} 
}
```

I get an error that SomePref is not set to an instance of an object, but I can't set it up because its a private seralizedfield. 
Now what is good practice to erase that error. I know, I could use Resource.Load in the Start Methode from MainController, but is this the good way?

Comment: Makes sense because usually you would set it via the Inspector ... if you are creating this instance new via `AddComponent` then obviously it won't have anything attached. You should maybe rather use something like  `if(SomePrefab) SomePrefab.SetActive(true);` in order to avoid the exception since your test is rather about whether the `Instance` is initialized correctly and doesn't require the `SomePrefab` to work as expected

Comment: You could assign anything to it if you really need to. Like e.g. `var prefab = new GameObject("Test prefab"); empty.GetComponent<MainController>().SomePref = prefab;` but this would require at least something being `public` in your `MainController` class, either `SomePref` or a method that sets it. The only alternative I guess would be Reflection. Or as said not initialize it if it is not required for your test